# How to bring the size of Dropdown equal to textbox size using Bootstrap?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have many fields in my view .

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id ="StartTime">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my TextBox Code.

[image: StartTime]

[image: POVisit]

See My `DropDown` Size. Now what I want is I want to bring my `Dropdown` size equal to `TextBox` size I tried the same code which i gave in `Textbox` but it showing error for `Dropdown`.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.POVisit, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownList("POVisitID", "Select")
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my `Dropdown` code. please any one help me to bring the `dropdown` size is equal to `textbox` size ..

Advance Thanks.

Comment: No need to add new { `type = "text" }` (the `TextBoxFor()` method already adds that. Add `new { @class = "form-control" }` to your `DropDownList()` method

Comment: ok stephen lets i have a try

Comment: stephen i did as per you said but it showing error

Comment: What error? - its `@Html.DropDownList("POVisitID", "Select", new { @class = "control-control" }) `

Comment: yes it showing erroe wait i will show you

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: [![Error][1]][1]    [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/I1mlR.jpg

Comment: see it showing error Stephen

Comment: Oops sorry, you need to add `null` as the 2nd parameter `@Html.DropDownList("POVisitID", null, "Select", new { @class = "control-control" })` - but stop using it and use the strongly typed `DropDownListFor()` method

Comment: Yes stephen its working thanks..

Comment: Stephen one more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `class="control-control`" to your `<select>` element using

```
@Html.DropDownList("POVisitID", null, "Select", new { @class = "control-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

The class "form-control" should be on the select element.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: class `"control-label"` is for a label :)

Comment: Control label is for label kasper

Comment: i want to bring the size of dropdown equal to textbox

Answer (score 0):

I think you will  use this class :form-control

```
 <select class="form-control" id="dropdown1">
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
   <option>C</option>
   <option>V</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: My dropdown getting values directly from Db mohsin

Comment: No problem,from where your value came from,just add class to your select tag.checkout this at end
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms